# Twilio: test speaker/microphone

Tags: testing, twilio, loopback

Using Twilio, how can I create a JS widget that can listen to the microphone and output its sound through the speakers, as a loopback?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't believe you need Twilio for that. You can just use the [`getUserMedia` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to capture a user's microphone and then play it back with an HTML5 `<audio>` tag.

I'd like to recommend you don't do this though. Whilst building video chats and testing with myself, the feedback is horrible and no-one wants to experience it!